# Difference when taking %string% and %tring%

Tags: laravel

I'm building a PC components selection guide and I came across this situation where 'MATX' and 'ATX' gets called even when my initial query has only ['ATX', 'EATX']

Column samples:

[image]

```
foreach($req->formFactor as $forms)
{
    $caseQuery = $caseQuery->where('form_factors', 'like', "%$forms%");
}
```

This is most likely due to (a) my mishandling in the column-per-component, and (b) using % wildcard at the query. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: `%ATX%` would match with both `ATX` and `MATX` that is correct. You should not use `like` operator if you don't want this.

Comment: yep, trying to look for a workaround since form_factors column is straight-up concatenated string (``` "ITX","DTX","MATX","ATX","EATX" ``` on one data, and ``` "ITX","MATX" ``` on the other )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wildcards? Why not just directly match the keywords? Referring to the example you gave, your data is `['ATX', 'EATX']`, assuming you just want to match `'ATX'` and `'EATX'`, and you don't want to match `'MATX'`, just remove the wildcards from your query (just `$forms` without the %).

Also, you don't need to loop through the form factors. Laravel has the `whereIn` method to search for multiple terms with one query.

Try this:

```
$result = $caseQuery->whereIn('form_factors', $req->formFactor);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Hi, wouldn't work with whereIn. I'm basically searching a varchar column with an array (updated the main question with an image sample)

Comment: Ah. Do you have any control over the database? This is best handled with a many-to-many relationship. Otherwise, you'll have to retrieve every single row, parse it and compare them one by one.

Comment: yep, i have the control of it. am considering it as last option if there aren't any workarounds aside using a loop of sql like